# Cryptographic API usage and software reverse engineering

Tags: c++, cryptography, reverse-engineering, cracking

I came down to a dilemma where input from people with more experience in this area would be very valuable. Considering a desktop software that needs to perform some general cryptographic tasks like AES and digital signature verification - what are the tradeoffs between using an open source library like crypto++ vs native APIs on each OS? The things that worry me are:

- Ability to crack the software. In a situation where someone would want to reverse engineer/crack the software OS calls would be much easier to trace thus the attacker could faster identify the places in code where any cryptographic stuff happens and get a starting point for assembly inspection. Whereas usage of open source cryptographic libs, if code was inlined, would be harder to spot. Then again most likely the attacker could patch the code somewhere else to short circuit the path that performs any validations etc., so maybe this is irrelevant.
- Newly identified threat prevention. Any security flaws in the algorithms would be targeted by OS updates (in case of native API usage) where as in case of open source libraries a new software release would be required and in the worst case it could take more time for the maintainer of the library to update it, than for an OS update.

Maybe there are other relevant aspects when making this decision?

Comment: Concentrate your initial efforts on key storage/usage.  If you can't protect the keys used then any effort you put into APIs,  code protection etc are wasted.

Comment: Avoid closed-source crypto.  If you can't find bugs, you can't fix them.

Comment: @stark well it's not like im inspecting crypto++ sources, even though I'm using it. Of course there could be an argument that the community would find them faster than the developers of a closed source OS. But I really dont have a strong feeling wether its true or not.

Comment: Reverse engineering is something that has been solved; just inlining your code won't do you any good and may harm updating a specific module. As for the quality of open source vs closed source; well, I'm not sure, both have their own spawn of good and bad developers. You may want to use a library that has received reviews or (FIPS) certification. C/assembly will give the library designer a lot of freedom to e.g. secure / destroy key material, but it will expose *you* to buffer overruns etc. If unsure use a container format e.g. NaCl. Key management and protocol usage is most important, I agree

Comment: If you only care about Windows I would use Windows native libraries. A) they protect the rest of the OS and inbox apps. B) they’re definitely FIPS certified. And definitely C) in the event of a problem Windows Update is your friend. But, that’s just my opinion, and it seems like this question can only be answered with opinions, so I voted to close.

Comment: I have to agree here, any answer could be questioned and the fact that we're all commenting instead of answering reflects this fact.